# Java Graphics2D drawString result confusion when scale Font size

Tags: java, fonts, awt, bufferedimage, java-2d

I use drawString by Font1, suppose deriveFont is 20f.

```java
final int width = fontMetrics.stringWidth(text);
final int height = fontMetrics.getHeight();
BufferedImage rendered = new BufferedImage(
    width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
);
System.out.println("render:" + width + "," + height);
final Graphics2D gOfRendered = (Graphics2D) rendered.getGraphics();
    
gOfRendered.setRenderingHints(getRenderingHints());
gOfRendered.setColor(fontColor);
gOfRendered.setFont(fontMetrics.getFont());
    
gOfRendered.drawString(
    text, 0, height - fontMetrics.getMaxDescent() - fontMetrics.getLeading()
);
```

result:

[image]

But when I scale font size(scale=4 result maybe normal,scale=8 will cause error result):

```java
final Font font = (wordFrequency.hasFont() ? wordFrequency.getFont() : kumoFont).getFont().deriveFont(fontHeight * 1.0f);
final Font font2 = (wordFrequency.hasFont() ? wordFrequency.getFont() : kumoFont).getFont().deriveFont(fontHeight * scale * 1.0f);
final FontMetrics fontMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics(font);
final FontMetrics fontMetrics2 = graphics.getFontMetrics(font2);
```

and render again:

```java
final int width = fontMetrics2.stringWidth(text);
final int height = fontMetrics2.getHeight();
BufferedImage rendered = new BufferedImage(
    width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
);
final Graphics2D gOfRendered = (Graphics2D) rendered.getGraphics();
    
// set the rendering hint here to ensure the font metrics are correct
gOfRendered.setRenderingHints(getRenderingHints());
gOfRendered.setColor(fontColor);
gOfRendered.setFont(fontMetrics2.getFont());
    
gOfRendered.drawString(
    text, 0, height - fontMetrics2.getMaxDescent() - fontMetrics2.getLeading()
);
```

Error result(scale=8):

[image]

I find `final int width = fontMetrics2.stringWidth(text);` is not 8 times the font width,the Numbers are very different,How to fix it?Thank you!

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Rather than use `drawString` or variants, I'll get typicall a `Shape` of the text and do further manipulations on that shape.